# can autocompletetextfield restrict user typing name not on list

Tags: java, html, autocomplete

I'm working on Java and I want to restrict users from submitting the form if they typed a name that is not in my autocomplete textfield. Is there a method to do this?

Comment: I have been trying to use a for loop and I am getting the error (feedback panel) message repeated on my form the number of times of the size of my array...which is not what I want, thus I'm wondering if there's a special method I can use to accomplish the free text entry of the autocomplete

Comment: @NielsBillen I just looked up your name. I hope you can help or refer me to someone else who can. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fight my way through  and found the solution:

```
    final List<MyClass> myList = DatabaseAccessUtil.getName();
    final List<String> lodgeNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
    {
        lodgeNames.add(myList.get(i).getGuestName());
    }

    lodges.add(
    new IValidator<String>() 
    { 
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
        public void validate(IValidatable<String> validatable) 
        { 
            if (!lodgeNames.contains(validatable.getValue())) 
            { 
                validatable.error(new ValidationError(validatable.getValue() + " is not in the list. Please select establisment name from the list.")); 
            } 
        } 
    });
```